# Keyed Particle System ( Renders static particles associated with each keyed mesh)

Tags: rendering, animation, particles

I have a keyed particle system animating from one mesh to another. 
[image: KEYED PARTICLE SYSTEM]

In the picture above the the particles between the sphere and cube animate as they should and transition/morph as they should from one mesh to the other, however the particles forming the sphere and cube are static and show across all frames of the animation. Hopefully I am missing something simple here?!

How can I make it so that the 'static' particles associated with each of the keyed meshes are not shown/rendered?

Answer (score 1):

I must have been getting confused between the RENDER and DISPLAY tool panels!
Within the RENDER tool panel it is as simple as selecting 'NONE'
[image]